# Best Practice for releasing 2 versions of app

Tags: android, release, release-management

I'd like to release 2 versions of my app, a PRO version that you have to pay for and a FREE version. The only difference is (so far), that the FREE version has ads and the PRO version doesn't, so only few lines of code difference. Still I want to be able to give away the PRO version for free (for example to the beta-testers). What is the best practice to do that? Especially I have the following questions:

1. Should I give them the .apk of the PRO version? I don't like the idea of giving this .apk away. BTW: Can you somehow get the .apk of an installed paid app? I assume you can't because wouldn't these be shared too easily then?
2. An idea is to give both versions the identical code including a boolean PRO. In the free version it is false, in the paid version it is true. Additionally in the free version it can be set to true after entering a secret code. This has the disadvantage that if the secret code gets leaked somehow, everyone gets the PRO version easily. But how if I would make the code depend on some device specific constants?
3. Do I need to change the package name if I release 2 versions?

Thank you very much in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can always publish 2 different apks, the PRO and the FREE, a lot of developers in Google Play, for example, follow this way. With this you don't need a boolean which probably is going to be stored in a setting which is easily modifiable in any rooted phone.

To handle the development of this 2 version you can use branches (managed by any software versioning tool, such as GIT or SVN) and directly merge the changes from one to another (PRO to FREE, for example).

Answer (score 0):

If you publish 2 apps, then you have 2 .apks, and thus make different approach. One to be free and another to be payable.

Or you can have only one app, which serves ads, and if user pays (via app, for exapmle some tokens) then he will become pro member and will not be served ads. This is some kind of freemium option..